# How to tell an ajax request in ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

IN PHP its like this but in Ruby is how

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") {
    }else{
        // header("Location: " . base_url());
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an `xhr?` method on the request object that you can use. So in your controller:

```
request.xhr?
```

will return true or false depending on whether the request was sent as an XMLHttpRequest.